# Filter value that starts with JS

Tags: javascript

I try to search if a value exists as first word.
ex: "My name is James" , if I search for "nam" => true, if I search for "ja" => true, if I search for "ame" false.
The logic it works but I don't receive any items at the end.

```js
let text = 'ame';
    let option_location = [
       {"text": "James"},
       {"text": "Valkar"},
       {"text": ""},
       {"text": "James2"},
    ];


    // This works but not as I wanted
    let itemsLocation = '';
    itemsLocation = option_location.filter(item => item.text.includes('ame'));
    console.log('Values', itemsLocation);

    // This is not working
    let itemsLocation2 = '';
    itemsLocation2 = option_location.filter(item =>{
        item.text = item.text.toLowerCase();
        let words = item.text.split(" ");
        words.forEach((element,index) => {
            if(element.startsWith(text)){
                return true;
           }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    console.log('Values', itemsLocation2);
```

Comment: Can you make this a runnable snippet?

Comment: Could you reduce this to a _minimal_, runnable example, without all the `this` stuff? I think you'll find in the process that `return`ing from a `forEach` does not have the desired effect.

Comment: use `return words.some(word => word.startsWith(text))` instead of `words.forEach`

Comment: I made I runnable snippet.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't run though. `Cannot read property 'option_location' of undefined"` because you still have a `this` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return words.some(...)` instead of `forEach`.  Returning in a `forEach` doesn't do anything for the result of the function passed to the `filter`.

The return in the `forEach` just returns from one iteration of the `forEach` and the `true`/`false` value is thrown away.  It does not return a result immediately to the predicate of the `filter`.

```
this.itemsLocation2 = this.option_location.filter(item =>{
    item.text = item.text.toLowerCase();
    let words = item.text.split(" ");
    words.forEach((element,index) => {
        if(element.startsWith(text)){
            return true; // returns from one forEach iteration, not from filter.
       }else{
            return false; // returns from one forEach iteration, not from filter.
        }
    });
});
```

Use a technique like this instead:

```js
let text = 'My name is James';

let searches = ['nam', 'ja', 'ame'];

let words = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");
for(let searchTerm of searches) {
  let found = words.some(w => w.startsWith(searchTerm));
  console.log(`${searchTerm} => ${found}`);
}
```

Comment: I try to implement your code, but your running code, is really different from mine. I try to figure it out.

Comment: Done, I figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you used `startswith()` function which checks if the word starts with the given string which obviously `name` does not start with `ame`.

Whereas `James` starts with `ja` and `name` starts with `nam`

The `includes()` function just checks if the word contains the given string no matter where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this. Use `filter` and combination with `startsWith`

```js
const option_location = [
  { text: "James" },
  { text: "Valkar" },
  { text: "" },
  { text: "James2" }
];

const items = (data, text) =>
  data.filter(item => text.split(" ").some(word => item.text.startsWith(word)));

console.log(items(option_location, "he ame"));
console.log(items(option_location, "ok Ja"));
```

Comment: This works ok just for first word, but I need to take each word from a string.

Comment: @Beusebiu, Oh I see. I just updated the answer. Hope I understood correctly. Can you please update questions with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify things by using regular expressions.
The expression would be:

```
/\W[your key without brackets]/gmi
```

In JavaScript it would look like this:

```js
/* The needles */
var needle1 = 'nam';
var needle2 = 'ja';
var needle3 = 'ame';

/* The haystack to search for */
var haystack = 'My name is James';

/* The code */
var exp1 = new RegExp('\\W' + needle1, 'gmi');
var matches1 = haystack.match(exp1);
console.log('Needle 1 found:', matches1 !== null);

var exp2 = new RegExp('\\W' + needle2, 'gmi');
var matches2 = haystack.match(exp2);
console.log('Needle 2 found:', matches2 !== null);

var exp3 = new RegExp('\\W' + needle3, 'gmi');
var matches3 = haystack.match(exp3);
console.log('Needle 3 found:', matches3 !== null);
```

Hope that helps :-)